# Google Barcode API PDF417 not working

Tags: android, barcode, google-vision

I've followed the directions in the Google codelab to get the Baracode API to detect and decode a standard QR code. I've done a simple integration to get the camera to provide the image and it works. Then I try a PDF417 bar code, and nothing.

```
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
            getApplicationContext().getResources(),
            R.drawable.barcode);

    BarcodeDetector detector =
            new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.PDF417)
            .build();

    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(myBitmap).build();

    SparseArray<Barcode> barcodes = detector.detect(frame);

    Barcode thisCode = barcodes.valueAt(0);
```

*barcodes* is a zero length object and thisCode fails trying to get the value at position 0. I've tried feeding a PDF417 barcode I took a picture of as well as a barcode from an online generator.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can you show what your PDF417 barcode looks like. Does it decode with ZXing using your device/camera?

Comment: Yes, they decode with ZXing. I used an online barcode generator by  [TEC-IT](https://barcode.tec-it.com/en/PDF417?data=This%20is%20a%20PDF417%20by%20TEC-IT)

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer to your question, you either need to change the barcode flag to ALL_FORMATS (Barcode.ALL_FORMATS) or you should only provide the barcode. In other words, there should be no other visual information alongside the barcode (crop it). Otherwise, the API can't find the PDF-417 barcode.